# Загрузить PDF из php rest api

Tags: php, pdf, base64

php rest api генерирует PDF в виде blob, как получить файл на фронтенде без сохранения на сервере.
Мое решение

```
public function getPdf($request)
{
    //генерируем PDF

    return array('file' => base64_encode($res));
}
```

Фронтенд (angular2)

```
getPdf(data) {
return this.api.post('/pdf', data)
  .map(res => atob(res.file))
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      FileSaver.saveAs(new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'}), "BusinessCard.pdf");
    },
    err => console.error(err)
  );}
```

Похоже проблема с кодировкой на фронте, пробовал вместо atob использовать решение с MDN, base64js... выдает ошибку URIError: URI malformed

Если декодировать вручную через https://www.base64decode.org/, с настройкой UTF-8 то все получается правильно

Comment: А вы исходный код https://www.base64decode.org/ смотрели? Может быть он это на клиенте делает?

Comment: Смотрел, там на сервере обработка((

Comment: Хм, возможно ещё decodeUri перед atob нужно сделать

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте base64 **urlsafe** decode 
`atob(res.file.replace(/_/g, '/').replace(/-/g, '+'))`

Comment: Спасибо за предложение, не сработало - те же проблемы кодировки((